# Firebase Auth: retrieving email address for all the connected providers except for phone

Tags: android, email, firebase, firebase-authentication, facebook-sdk-4.x

I have a firebase user in android where the user can attach multiple providers to the account. Now I'm able to connect multiple accounts successfully but later when I want to get the emails for the providers connected to the account using the code below it returns null for email, even for the providers who have successfully returned the email address during linking.

```
for (UserInfo userInfo : firebaseUser.getProviderData()) {
    Log.i(userInfo.getUid(),userInfo.getProviderId()+ " " +userInfo.getEmail());
}
```

Is it a bug in sdk for android? Or I'm missing something to retrieve the providers emails.

I'm using the procedures given by firebase docs to link the accounts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is fixed now in Firebase SDK version 12.0.0.

Here is the link to my sample project using the above mentioned sdk and successfully provides email address for the attached providers.

https://github.com/umarhussain15/FirebaseAuthProviderLinking